# Detect if username is already taken and display a errormessage to the person?

Tags: java, php, android

What you see below in PHP and JAVA files are a complete (although simple) registration functionality. It all works.

The question now is,

How do I detect if the username field is already taken , and how do I let the java side know that so I can give the user a proper message.

**ORIGINAL register.php:**

```
<?php

define('HOST','X');
define('USER','X');
define('PASS','X');
define('DB','X');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $pass = $_POST['pass'];

  $sql = "insert into tbl_user (username,password) values ('$name','$pass')";
  if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    echo 'success';
  }
  else{
    echo 'failure';
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

**Part of register.java:**

```
private void insertToDatabase(String name, String pass) {
    class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String name = params[0];
            String pass = params[1];

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", pass));

        boolean exists = false;


        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://calisapp.esy.es/register.php");
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, MainActivity.class);

        startActivity(intent);
        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Registered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
}
SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(name, pass);
```

}

Comment: If your db collation is case insensitive you can make the username field unique index?

Comment: check username before insert and make username column unique in user table

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). And if youw ant to tell java something, then you have to OUTPUT something. e.g. `if (record exists) { echo "duplicate" }`, then look for `duplicate` in the java code.

Comment: Yea ill be changing the whole sql injection thing after I'm done with this part of the app. Anyone have a code example?

Comment: Set a `unique` constraint on the field in the table. Attempt to insert, and if you get the error `duplicate key` or similar then display an error about the username being taken. Requires that you use error handling obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void insertToDatabase(String name, String pass) {
class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
   String name = params[0];
   String pass = params[1];
   List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", pass));
   try {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(                   "http://calisapp.esy.es/register.php");
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    InputStream entity = response.getEntity().getContent();
    InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader(entity);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStream);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String bufferedStrChunk = null;
    while ((bufferedStrChunk = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(bufferedStrChunk);
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
  } catch (IOException e) {
  }
    return "";
}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      super.onPostExecute(result);
      try {
       JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(result);
       String status = jo.getString("status");
       if (status.equals("0")) {
         editTextName.requestFocus();
         editTextName.setError("Username already exists.");
       } else if (status.equals("1")) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, MainActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
         Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Registered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         finish();
       }else if (status.equals("2")) {
         // failed to register
       }
     } catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
}
 SendPostReqAsyncTask sendPostReqAsyncTask = new SendPostReqAsyncTask();
 sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute(name, pass);
```

}

Comment: Mate, I can't possibly express my gratitude in words. I was stuck on this for days! I think I will forever and always hate referencing to different types of script (Like Java to PHP). Thank you very much! This made it work exactly how I needed it to. I learned alot Deepak, have a great day.

Comment: welcome buddy. If you are happy, then please flag my answer

Comment: I did. Happen to know this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685210/android-studio-xml-how-to-get-imageview-in-front-of-button

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
define('HOST','X');
define('USER','X');
define('PASS','X');
define('DB','X');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

$name = $_POST['name'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

$query = "SELECT * from tbl_user where username = '$name'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$n = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($n>0){
  $data = array(
        'status'    => 0,
        'message' => 'Username already exists'
  );
}else{
  $sql = "insert into tbl_user (username,password) values ('$name','$pass')";
  if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    $data = array(
        'status'    => 1,
        'message' => 'Successfull'
  );
  }else{
    $data = array(
        'status'    => 2,
        'message' => 'Failed'
  );
  }
}
mysqli_close($con);
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

and on the java side the result parameter in the onpostexecute method

```
try {
    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(result);
    String status = jo.getString("status");
    if (status.equals("0")) {
      // show the error, username already exists
    } else if (status.equals("1")) {
      // registration successfull
    }else if (status.equals("2")) {
      // failed to register
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any idea on how I can reference that the username already exists with java? I reckon I can't reference to a echo?

Comment: I believe the echo will be visible in the response as a string.

Comment: Okay, so I added a, echo json_encode($usertaken) to the php code from deepak. However, I have no idea how to decode it in java. I simply want it to show this error when that json code is returned:    editTextName.requestFocus();
            editTextName.setError("Username is already taken.");
        } Any ideas?

Comment: just print or toast the response and check what comes.

Comment: i have updated my code, please check it and let me know.

Comment: In bed so Ill check it right after breakfast. Cant point out anything wrong with it from a first glance. Ill comment tomorrow! Please check back !

Comment: Could you add the java code to my java code above? I can't seem to get it to work!