# Android Studio XML - How to get imageview in front of button?

Tags: android, xml, button, android-studio, imageview

The question is quite simple. How do I get this imageview below to be visible in front of the button below?

I am looking for an XML answer, not a Java answer. Seeing java (I think) will not change anything in the preview screen while working on the xml file.

```
 <ImageView
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@drawable/iconfb"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12.5pt"
        android:id="@+id/iconfb"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="Sign in with facebook"
        android:onClick="invokefb"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@color/tmfacebook"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12.5pt"
    android:id="@+id/fblogin"
    "/>
```

Comment: So you want imageview and button together in a line. If yes, then there are attributes like drawableLeft or drawableRight in the button tag.
It is even better if you post a screenshot, what exactly do you want.

Comment: Let's say they both have the same margins so they overlap. The image is just a small icon that I would like in-front of the button so you can actually see it. Right now the button overlaps the icon.

Comment: so for that you don't need to add separate image view. just use drawableLeft to the button and provide your drawable.

Comment: If you don't get it i will post the xml code here.

Comment: It's working now. It is one of these things you keep googling wrong cause you think it is harder. Is there any way I can control the padding of my hint text in the button seperately? It now cant be centered anymore cause it counts the drawableleft.

Comment: Never mind Deepak. Found it. There is a 'drawablepadding'. Did not know that. Thanks again!

Comment: you can use android:drawablePadding in your button tag

Comment: Great.....!!!!!!
If you need any other help, please let me know.

Comment: Well you helped me alot! Let me show a picture of how it currenty looks so you know I am 100% dedicated to the app. http://imgur.com/noLLX9I,hMtvaWK | http://imgur.com/noLLX9I,hMtvaWK#1

Comment: Great, it looks perfect...!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Button 
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/fb"
        android:text="Facebook"/>
```